# Mostrar índide de todos los elementos en un array biDimiensional

Tags: java, array, arraylist, array-bidimensional, index

estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar el índice de un array biDimensional utilizando Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(elemento); Lo pude hacer con un array uniDimensional (subo el código de ejemplo), pero no logro hacerlo con el biDimiensional. Se muestra el índice de los tres primeros elementos y luego vuelve a cero el índice. Alguien sabrá como resolverlo? Gracias

------------ESTO ES LO QUE OBTENGO COMO RESULTADO--------------

```
Estas en la fila 0 
Elemento: 1 ; Posición0 
Elemento: 2 ; Posición1 
Elemento: 3 ; Posición2 
Estas en la fila 1 
Elemento: 4 ; Posición0 
Elemento: 5 ; Posición1 
Elemento: 6 ; Posición2 
Estas en la fila 2 
Elemento: 7 ; Posición0 
Elemento: 8 ; Posición1 
Elemento: 9 ; Posición2
```

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayBidimiensional {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    // Mostrar indice de un array uniDimensional
        
        Integer[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
                int indice = array1[j];
                 System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array1).indexOf(indice));
        }
        
        // Mostrar indice de un array biDimensional
        
        Integer [][] enteros = new Integer[3][3];
        
        enteros[0][0] = 1;
        enteros[0][1] = 2;
        enteros[0][2] = 3;
        enteros[1][0] = 4;
        enteros[1][1] = 5;
        enteros[1][2] = 6;
        enteros[2][0] = 7;
        enteros[2][1] = 8;
        enteros[2][2] = 9;
        
        

        for (int i = 0; i < enteros.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Estas en la fila " + i);
            for (int j = 0; j < enteros[i].length; j++) {
                int elemento = enteros[i][j];
                System.out.println("Elemento: " + elemento + " " + "; Posición" + 
                Arrays.asList(enteros[i]).indexOf(elemento));
                
            }
        }
                
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Pero que vuelva a cero es lo correcto....cual sería tu resultado esperado?

Comment: Entiendo! yo esperaba que me devuelva el índice del 0 al 8 como en el array uniDimensional. Pero por tu respuesta me doy cuenta no se lee igual el indice en un array biDimensional. Gracias

Comment: Piénsalo como un tablero de ajedrez o un sistema de coordenadas (X,Y) tienes las filas 0,1,2 y las columnas 0,1,2.. Tus casillas serian (0,0) - (0,1) - (0,2) - (1,0) - (1,1) - (1,2) - (2,0) - (2,1) - (2,2)